# Dynamic website with monitoring

Tags: javascript, monitoring

I want to create a website which monitors a text file on the same domain, and updates a paragraph automatically when the text file changes. Any good ideas on what i can possibly use?

I feel like having a JavaScript file running a loop which monitors the file is not good practice, so any other suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it on the client, you can't automatically access the users file system. You need to open the file using dialog, select the file.

Once you have the file you can use the `lastModified` property of the file to check when it was modified. If you store the reference to that file you can then create an interval which will check every x if the file changed.

One global variable to keep track of most recent file modification date (so later we can compare if it's different)

```
var lastModificationDate = undefined;
```

Then when file is selected, you want to get the file and set the `lastModificationDate` property and start the interval.

```
file = input.files[0];
lastModificationDate = file.lastModified;
setInterval(checkFile, 500);
```

Your `checkFile` function would look like:

```
var file = input.files && input.files[0];
if (file && lastModificationDate && file.lastModified.getTime() != lastMod.getTime()) {
   lastModificationDate = file.lastModified;
   // Do something else, file was modified
}
```

The above functionality is achieved using `HTML5 File API`, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

---

For a Node.js solution:
Use the `fs.watchFile` functionality built into the core of Nodes File System module.

```
fs.watchFile('message.text', (curr, prev) => {
  console.log(`the current mtime is: ${curr.mtime}`);
  console.log(`the previous mtime was: ${prev.mtime}`);
});
```

`mtime` is the modification time in the snippet above. This function would automatically fire on file change once implemented, unlike the solution above for client side.

You can read more about [`fs.watchFile` here.](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener)